What does “三年相邦吕不韦造寺工詟丞义工窎”铜戟 mean?
“三年相邦吕不韦造寺工詟丞义工窎”铜戟 is the words I saw in a reading material of the Emperor Qinshihuang of the Qin Dynasty. It looks like a sort of ancient weapon, but what about the words before that weapon?
Do they mean the quality, the brand, the material, the history, the owner or what else of the weapon?

http://m.cnwest.com/sxxw/a/2021/01/07/19419272.html, the 2nd paragraph explained

Before the others pointed to this link, I thought part of the text was garbled. However, they didn't provide a translation and it is hard to put it in a comment, I will give it as an answer

三年 = the third year (of Emperor Qin Shihuang)

相邦吕不韦 = Prime Minister Lu Buwei (Who is the highest overseer of weapons manufacturing)

造 = made

寺工 is the name of the central government agency responsible for casting weapons,

詟/zhé/ is the name of the head of the 寺工 department

丞 is the title of the officer who assists 寺工 and manages the craftsmen

the 丞 officer's name was 义/Yi/

工窎 - the craftsman 窎/diào/

铜戟- Bronze Halberd



"三年相邦吕不韦造寺工詟丞义工窎"

Made in the third year of Emperor Qin Shihuang
Supreme supervisor of weapons manufacturing department: Prime Minister 吕不韦 (Lu Buwei)
Head of weapons manufacturing department: 詟/zhé/
Craftsmen manager: 义/Yi/
Craftsman (maker of this weapon): 窎/diào/
This text recorded a particular weapon's maker and the maker's supervisors at each level. This way, when there's a problem, they know whom to blame.

“三年相邦吕不韦造寺工詟[zhé]丞义工窎[diào]” 是，"秦俑坑出土青铜兵器上的铭文, 文字的内容，多数是仅有一二个字的编号，少数是带有纪年和督造者、制造者名字的铭文。"

“三年”即秦始皇三年，指兵器铸造的年代；“相邦吕不韦”是指兵器制造的最高督造者，“寺工”是中央负责铸造兵器的官署机构名称，“詟”为人名，是“寺工”官署的负责人，“丞”是“寺工”机构中协助“寺工”负责人管理工匠的官职名，“义”是协助者的人名；“工窎”是指具体铸造这件兵器的工匠，名字叫窎。这种兵器刻铭题记是秦始皇初期的标准格式。

http://m.cnwest.com/sxxw/a/2021/01/07/19419272.html
